# as Int vs toInt(), what's the difference between the two?

Tags: kotlin

I have the question

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){
    val aa = "1"
    val bb = aa.toInt()  // <----- no problem
    println(bb)

    var cc = "1"
    var dd = cc as Int   // <----- exception
    println(dd)
}
```

if I use `as` then what happens is...

Compiler : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at MainKt.main(main.kt:7)

Comment: `toInt()` converts to `Int`. `as Int` just tries to cast to `Int`, which isn't valid for these two types as the exception states.

Answer (score 1):

`as Int` *casts* something which is already an Int to the type `Int`.

```
val x:Any = 5
val xInt = x as Int
```

`.toInt()` *parses* a string that represents an Int.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov it must be already an Int you can't cast a `Long` to `Int` with as, there are not inheritance relationships there.

Comment: I assumed Kotlin inherited that ugliness from Java and didn't even check. Good that it actually can't.